# How to tell if folder is a subfolder for recursive folder copy?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I'm trying to implement a folder copy method that calls `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` in a loop, that may call itself recursively on any subfolders.

To prevent an obvious infinite loop I need to make sure that the destination folder is not a subfolder of a source folder. The question is how to do that? My thinking was to translate a DOS path into a device specific path (need to find out how) but there seems to be more to it.

So I'm testing it for this situation:

I set up `My Documents` folder to be redirected to a network share to `\\Server\Home\UserA\Documents`, plus that folder is also mapped to the drive `R:` on the client machine. So that means that all of the following folders:

```
"R:\Documents\Subfolder1"
"\\Server\Home\UserA\Documents\Subfolder1"
"C:\Users\UserA\Documents\Subfolder1"
```

point technically to the same physical location, that is a subfolder of `My Documents`.

The question is how to know this reliably?

Comment: If you are iterating through a folder hierarchy, how are you expecting to encounter multiple folders that map to the same folder? Unless you use symbolic links or junctions (which can both be detected during the iteration).

Comment: Oh, it can be easily done w/o symlinks. Say, if I specify `c:\Folder1` as the source folder and `c:\Folder1\Folder2` as the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the volume serial number and file index for the destination directory and for each possible match.  If both the serial number and the file index are the same, they are the same directory.

Note that you will need to use the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag in `CreateFile` in order to open a handle to a directory.  (You do not need backup privilege to do so.)

It may be possible for cloned volumes to have the same serial number (I'm not sure offhand whether Windows forces a serial number change or not) so it might be wise to provide an option to the user that disables this check.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution. Although what option would I give for the end-user? "_[x] Hang up the app and create one enormous folder on my disk_" :)

Comment: *"[x] Shut up, I know what I'm doing"* :-)  But seriously, my command-line application has a `/nofileids` option.  On the other hand, I'm the only one that uses it, so I didn't need to worry about it being misunderstood ... you could hide it in a registry setting or something.  Alternatively, if you wanted to explicitly support this scenario without user intervention, when you detect possible recursion you could create a temporary file with a unique name and see whether it shows up on the "other volume" or not.

Comment: Haha. Good one. I should add an "Easter egg" like that. But, seriously, how would I detect a run-away recursion? You know, infinite loop type.

Comment: In the most general case I suppose you might need to track the volume serial number and file index for each directory you copy (both the source and destination, I suppose) so you can tell if you've already seen one.  But depending on how you handle junction points and symbolic links it might only be necessary to check the top-level destination folder against each of the source folders as you come to them.

Comment: Symbolic links are the ones with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` attribute, right. But what are `junction points`?

Comment: Both symbolic links and junction points are implemented using reparse points.  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT should detect both.